# Python client socket event handling like that found in Adobe ActionScript

Tags: python, sockets, asyncore

I'm porting some ActionScript code to Python and I'm struggling with some sort of event dispatcher implementation similar to that available in Flash (flash.events.EventDispatcher).

I need to create a client socket connection to a server which will respond with a banner. The client will then send some information, receive a new banner etc.

I know how to create the client socket, but the problem is how to handle events, so that the client runs the appropriate functions depending on the events.

I've read a little about various modules such as Asyncore and Twisted and honestly I'm looking for something that is quick and easy to implement. I need to get the code ported with minimal fuss as a proof of concept.

**Here is part of my code using asyncore:**

```
import socket
import asyncore

class Client(asyncore.dispatcher):

    def __init__(self, host, port):
        asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self)
        self.create_socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.connect((host, port))

    def handle_connect(self):
        self.log('Socket connected')

    def handle_close(self):
        print "Socket disconnected"
        self.close()

    def handle_read(self):
        print 'Received: ', self.recv(1024)
        self.handle_close()

def connect(host, port)
    clientSocket = Client(host, port)
    asyncore.loop()
```

**For some reason the code returns the following error:**

```
warning: unhandled write event
warning: unhandled write event
warning: unhandled write event
...
```

The above code doesn't really do anything useful yet. I need to add event handlers for IO errors and for dealing with the data sent back and forth. However, first I need to get the basics sorted out.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I suggest using Twisted, it provides lots of glue for async network services: http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/

Answer (score 0):

Did you try overriding the `handle_write` event, as described in the [asyncore documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/asyncore.html#asyncore.dispatcher.handle_write)?

Edit: Alternatively, you can use the `-W` [command-line option](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-unittest-discover-W) or the [warnings](http://docs.python.org/library/warnings.html#module-warnings) module if you want to suppress the warning rather than override the event.

Comment: I added a handle_write function as you linked, but the handle_connect still doesn't run. I've been trying to figure this out for hours now. Maybe I should look at Twisted and how quickly I can use that instead.